# Microsoft Service Manager Console API?

Tags: c#, system-center

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on how to interact with the SCSM Console.
Almost all samples and documentation I stumble upon, are regarding interacting with the System Center Backend.

My goal is to have a TextBox and a Button, in the TextBox goes an Incident ID, and a click on the button would then open the incident in the SCSM Console.

I don't know if its even possible, does anyone of you have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with the SCSM SDK for 2 years now and have not come across anything within it which would allow you to launch the console and go straight to a particular incident form. The ConsoleContextHelper requires the console to be already open and mainly interacts with the current view/form.

lovedatsnow's suggestion for using a ConsoleTask on the incident view would be the closest way to implement something similar to what you desire however this wouldn't give much advantage over using the search bar and double clicking the result to open the form.

Answer (score -1):

I've walked through Travis Wright's post with success:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/servicemanager/2010/02/11/tasks-part-1-tasks-overview/

Here is a simpler tutorial that may also be helpful
https://blog.jhnr.ch/2013/12/09/how-to-create-a-custom-scsm-console-task-by-using-some-c-and-xml-magic/

Comment: Thanks, but its not really what i want.